# Why would one phone be compatible on a network but another not?

Tags: mobile-network, imei

I lost my Asus Zenfone 8.  I'm borrowing another one which has all the same specs per [imei.info](https://www.imei.info/).

However, when I [check the device's compatibility with the Cricket network](https://www.cricketwireless.com/prepaid-phones/bring-your-phone), his phone shows as incompatible.  When I enter my lost phone's IMEI, the site says it's compatible.

I'd like to understand how this could be.  i.e. why would phones with the same hardware be listed with different compatibilities on any given network?

Comment: Have you read the section "Check Device Compatibility & Unlock Status" on the linked cricket site? Devices can be carrier locked or even SIM locked so they are bound to one carrier or contract. Such a lock is implemented on software level.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the note.  I'll check with my friend but as far as I know this phone was only available unlocked.  i.e. I don't think asus partnered with any providers to sell locked variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting both Cricket and Asus support, Asus mentioned my friend's phone was intended for use in Taiwan.  They determined this based off the serial number.

This doesn't fully make sense to me since I believe the phone has the hardware support that Cricket says is missing - specifically VoLTE/HD-voice.  I found when I restarted the phone and swapped my SIM card into it, I could use the unsupported Asus phone for around 5 minutes before some automated process disabled both 5G and VoLTE (the icons on top-right were there, then disappeared after ~5 minutes).

So although I'd like to understand the lack of support at a deeper level, hearing the phone was intended to be used in Taiwan works well enough for me as he did buy it off eBay.

Comment: It seems *the carrier* blocks foreign/unregistered IMEI on their side. This also happened to my imported phone on Indonesian carriers due to [this regulation](https://come2indonesia.com/how-to-register-the-imei-of-the-mobile-to-be-able-to-use-it-in-indonesia/). The phone getting signal for about 30 minutes, then no signal since then.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience - good to know regulations like that exist since I didn't realize something like that would be regulated